# input function does not work & returns FileInput object

Tags: python, python-3.x, input

I'm trying to get user input as function call in a small python program but, when i'm using  the `input()` method, python shell does not let me input anything and quit by itself.

```
from fileinput import input
def funcinput():
    comm = input("-->")
    print('your input is %s' %comm)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("try to get input")
    funcinput()
```

Code looks like this and every time I run it, python launcher just give me:

```
try to get input
your input is <fileinput.FileInput object at 0x10464c208>
>>>
```

without let me input anything

What should I do to make it work?

Comment: There's something else you aren't showing in your actual code. It seems somewhere in your real code `comm` becomes a `FileInput` object.

Comment: yup you guys are all correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cause here is a masking of the built-in [`input`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/functions.html#input). In some point, a `from fileinput import input` occurs, which masks `builtins.input` and replaces it with [`fileinput.input`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/fileinput.html#fileinput.input). That function doesn't return an `str` but, instead, returns an instance of [`FileInput`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/fileinput.html#fileinput.FileInput):

```
>>> from fileinput import input
```

Using `input` now picks up `fileinput.input`:

```
>>> print(input("--> "))
<fileinput.FileInput at 0x7f16bd465160
```

If importing `fileinput` is *necessary* import the the module and access the `input` function using dot notation:

```
>>> import fileinput
>>> print(fileinput.input("--> ")) # fileinput input, returns FileInput instance.
>>> print(input("--> "))           # original input, returns str
```

If this option is failing (or, you have no control of imports for some reason), you could try and delete the imported reference to get the look-up for it to use the built-in version:

```
>>> from fileinput import input
>>> print(input("--> "))
<fileinput.FileInput at 0x7f16bd465f60>
```

Now by deleting the reference with `del input`:

```
>>> del input
>>> input("--> ")
-->
```

`input` works as it always does.

Comment: Thank you so much! I've been stuck here for a day